# How to post to the activities feed in yammer

Tags: yammer

I saw on a slide deck about yammer that activities was a valid endpoint in the REST APIs. But the yammer site does not show this. I am looking for a sample in JavaScript for posting to the activities feed.

Answer (score 0):

All of the documentation about Yammer's Activity Feed API can be found in the Open Graph documentation found here:

http://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/

Specifically, you want to POST to:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json

We don't have any specific Javascript samples available, but that should be enough to get you started.